# Aerospike: zlib/bz2 store and retrieve didnt worked

Tags: aerospike

I am compressing a string using zlib, then storing in Aerospike bin.  On retrieval and decompressing, I am getting "zlib.error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream"

When I compared original compressed data and retrieved compressed data, some thing is missing at the end in retrieved data.

I am using Aerospike 3.7.3 & python client 2.0.1

Please help

Thanks

**Update:** Tried using bz2. Throws ValueError: couldn't find end of stream while retrieve and decompress.  Looks like aerospike is stripping of the last byte or something else from the blob.

**Update:** Posting the code

```
import aerospike
import bz2

config = {
    'hosts': [
        ( '127.0.0.1', 3000 )
    ],
    'policies': {
        'timeout': 1000 # milliseconds
    }
}

client = aerospike.client(config)
client.connect()

content = "An Aerospike Query"
content_bz2 = bz2.compress(content)

key = ('benchmark', 'myset', 55)
#client.put(key, {'bin0':content_bz2})
(key, meta, bins) =  client.get(key)
print bz2.decompress(bins['bin0'])
```

Getting Following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asread.py", line 22, in <module>
    print bz2.decompress(bins['bin0'])
ValueError: couldn't find end of stream
```

Comment: How big is the data?

Comment: Very small about 20 bytes

Comment: Can you post a code sample of what you're doing?

Comment: Ronen, Updated the Question with code

Comment: Can anyone please help me out if this is a bug in Aerospike python client/Aerospike server or in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`bz.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html?highlight=bz2#bz2.compress) method returns a string, and the client sees that type and tries to convert it to the server's [`as_str`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/data-types.html#string) type. If it runs into a `\0` in an unexpected position it will truncate the string, causing your error.

Instead, make sure to cast binary data to a [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=bytearray#bytearray), which the client converts to the server's [`as_bytes`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/data-types.html#bytes) type. On the read operation, [`bz.decompress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html?highlight=bz2#bz2.decompress) will work with the `bytearray` data and give you back the original string.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import aerospike
import bz2

config = {'hosts': [( '33.33.33.91', 3000 )]}

client = aerospike.client(config)
client.connect()

content = "An Aerospike Query"
content_bz2 = bytearray(bz2.compress(content))

key = ('test', 'bytesss', 1)
client.put(key, {'bin0':content_bz2})
(key, meta, bins) =  client.get(key)
print(type(bins['bin0']))
bin0 = bz2.decompress(bins['bin0'])
print(type(bin0))
print(bin0)
```

Gives back

```
<type 'bytearray'>
<type 'str'>
An Aerospike Query
```

Comment: using zlib inplace of bz2 throws error "TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not bytearray"

Got resolved after typecasting to str before decompressing.

Thanks.